# "Do not track" option does not work on chrome 81

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Stack: python, selenium,  chrome 81.
Do not track feature does not work on chrome 81. The corresponding header is not being passed along with request.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
prefs = {"enable_do_not_track": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH", chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/is-do-not-track-enabled")
```

Comment: Please extend you error description beyond "does not work"!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you encounter has nothing to do with Selenium nor Chrome web driver nor Chrome version.

Preferences are not available for Chromium headless by its design.

If you check [Headless Chrome architecture](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11zIkKkLBocofGgoTeeyibB2TZ_k7nR78v7kNelCatUE/edit), you will see that it evolves around the content layer. You can read more about the [content module](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/content/README.md) on Chromium repository. Note that most of the modern web browser features like Extensions, Autofill etc. are also not available in the content module.

[Preferences](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/components/prefs/) belong to component layer so they are not included in the headles Chromium/Chrome.